Query is slow because of '#{}'
If I set "?stringtype=unspecified" in db url, I get imporvement on
Execution speed in mybatis. but I can't use the setting. I need help!
Is there a way to speed up execution when using #{} in MyBatis without relying on this setting? The problematic parameter is a String.
Thank you

Could you share a small demo project that demonstrates the speed difference? Here are some project templates and examples.

Without details, I can only provide generic advice. Common workaround may be 1) use the "right" type in Java side (e.g. if the column type is DATE, use java.time.LocalDate instead of String) or 2) create and specify custom type handler for each parameter e.g. #{date_column,typeHandler=com.foo.StringToDateTypeHandler}.
